# Get current location of a visitor

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net

I already found functionality that can give a users country or state using his or her IP address. But what I actually need is the exact location.

Like you can see on [this link](http://htmlfive.appspot.com/static/whereami.html), it is possible to get the very specific current location of a user.

How is this possible with ASP.NET C#, Javascript or jQuery?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535619/google-geolocation-api-library

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      onSuccess,
      onError, {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        timeout: 20000,
        maximumAge: 120000
      });

function onSuccess(position) {
      //the following are available to use
  //position.coords.latitude
  //position.coords.longitude
 // position.coords.altitude
 // position.coords.accuracy
 // position.coords.altitudeAccuracy
 // position.coords.heading
 // position.coords.speed 


}
```

[you can find details here](http://www.worldwidewhat.net/2011/08/find-out-you-visitors-positio-using-html5-geolocation/)

**Warning**:This will popup a permission dialog in browsers that will look something like this (Safari):
[image]

Answer (score 5):

You could use the [Geolocation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_geolocation) in JavaScript ... to get the current position use this :

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
  do_something(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
});
```

`do_something()` could be to update a map or just show the current longitude and latitude. [Nice simple example here](http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/aA2zv/)

Browser support ([Source](http://html5doctor.com/finding-your-position-with-geolocation/)):

- Firefox 3.5+
- Chrome 5.0+
- Safari 5.0+
- Opera 10.60+
- Internet Explorer 9.0+

[API Spec here](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html)

Comment: I'd upvote twice if I could since you DIDN'T refer to it as HTML5! :-)

Comment: Do you know how Google makes this possible to know the users exact location without GPS or something?